# Using curl to access JMX port

Tags: java, jmx

I have a jar that I got from one of my teams and I'm trying to connect to the JMX of the app and collect some metrics.

I configured JAVA_OPTS to be the following :

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8098 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 "
```

The Java app started successfully with the the new settings. I checked if the app listens on 9098/ and I saw it is :

```
[root@machine]# netstat -noap | grep -e "8098\|8099"
tcp6       0      0 :::8098                 :::*                    LISTEN      16365/java           off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8099                 :::*                    LISTEN      16365/java           off (0.00/0/0)
```

I tried to run the following curl commands but nothing is returned :

```
[root]# curl -i 127.0.0.1:9098/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
[root]# curl -i 127.0.0.1:9097/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Is it possible to reach out to the jmx port with an api call ?

Comment: (As per our last discussion, please use a spell-checker prior to posting).

Comment: To be honest, I'm using one :) Did u find something that I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

(For my system I set it up to use port 7770 for jmx on a box running cassandra)

To get a list of all available data:

```
echo "beans" | java -jar jmxterm-1.0.2-uber.jar -l localhost:7199 -n 2>&1 | less
```

To see a specific value:

```
curl http://localhost:7770/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=ClassLoading
```

For cassandra - connected clients:

```
 curl http://localhost:7770/jolokia/read/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:name=connectedNativeClients,type=Client/*
```